# Prove that for positive $a,b,c : a^2+b^2=c^2\Rightarrow a+b < c \sqrt 2.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Prove that for positive $a,b,c : a^2+b^2=c^2\Rightarrow a+b < c \sqrt
2.$

Is it solved considering a right isosceles triangle? I'm stuck on it

Comment: I think it should be $\leq$, not $<$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
(a+b)^2\leq 2(a^2+b^2)=2c^2\implies a+b\leq\sqrt{2}c.
$$
The first inequality holds because it is equivalent to $(a-b)^2\geq 0$. Equality **can** happen: $a=b=c/\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$a+b<c\sqrt2\iff a^2+b^2+2ab<2c^2\iff2ab<a^2+b^2\iff0<(a-b)^2$$

Answer (score 2):

(The inequality should not be strict)

$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ implies $a, b, c$ are the sides of a right triangle, with $c$ the hypotenuse. Let $\theta$ be one of the non-right angles. Then the sides of the triangle $a, b$ can be expressed as $c \cos \theta$ and $c \sin \theta$. Thus th einequality is $c(\cos \theta + \sin \theta) \leq c\sqrt{2}$, so $\cos \theta + \sin \theta \leq \sqrt{2}$

It is a well known fact that $|a \cos \theta + b \sin \theta| \leq \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$, and it can be proven like this:

For some arbitrary angle $\phi$, we can write $\cos \phi = \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$ and $\sin \phi = \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$ So $a \cos \theta + b \sin \theta = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} (\sin \phi \cos \theta + \cos \phi \sin \theta) = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \sin(\phi + \theta)$ and $|\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \sin (\phi + \theta)| \leq \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$. Equality holds when $\phi + \theta = \pi/2$.

Thus, $|\cos \theta + \sin \theta| \leq \sqrt{2}$ - we can ignore absolute value sign because $\cos x, \sin x \geq 0 \quad \forall x \in [0, \pi/2]$

Equality holds when $\theta = \pi/4$.